# how to show only last 100 lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a textarea element for a webpage that will show certain output as directed by the user.

For example

```
var Logger = {
  log: function (line) {
      $('logTextArea').append(line + '\n);
   }
}
```

Is there an easy way when I do the append to only keep the LAST 100 entries eliminate the rest?

Comment: Combine [`split`ing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on `\n` and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the last 100. Or you could [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) the first one off of the `split` array.

Comment: You can do a recursive loop when the user submits it (start from the last entry and move towards the start), where you find new lines the way you append them (with "\n").

Comment: Please be more specific about how this UI needs to work. *"directed by user"* is meaningless

Comment: Can the user edit the text in the textarea or is it read only?

Comment: You'll have better success getting a good answer if you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest just keeping an array of the lines, and just push the new lines onto it, and shift lines off. Then just use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert to a string and set your textarea to that value.

```js
var Logger = function() {
  var lines = [];
  return {
    log: function(line) {
      if (lines.length > 100) {
        lines.shift(); // remove the first line
      }
      lines.push(line); // add the new one
      $('#logTextArea').val(lines.join('\n'));
    }
  };
};
var logger = new Logger();
for (var x = 0; x < 110; x++) {
  logger.log(x.toString());
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="logTextArea"></textarea>
```

Note that I've updated your Logger object to be a function which returns an object. This makes it possible to keep track of the lines without exposing that to the rest of the world.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split on the new lines and slice the last 100 rows off. To make the demo shorter, I used 5 rows from the end.

```js
function addTime() {
   var ts = new Date().toLocaleString();
   var textarea = document.querySelector("#x");
   var txt = textarea.value.length ? textarea.value.split(/\n/g) : [];
   txt.push(ts);
   textarea.value = txt.slice(-5).join("\n");
}

window.setInterval(addTime, 1000);
```

```html
<textarea id="x" rows="10"></textarea>
```